# multiple widgets in Kivy

Tags: python, widget, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to python front-end. Currently i am stuck with integrating 2 python kivy programs. 
Each of them have different widget. One is asynchronous image loading and one is clock widget.
Can anyone help me to integrate this multiple widgets in a sigle python file. I am adding my python codes below. please help me.

**Asynchronus image loading**

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<CenteredAsyncImage>:
    allow_stretch: True
    keep_ratio: True
    size_hint_y: None
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    height: dp(800)
    mipmap: True
''')

class CenteredAsyncImage(AsyncImage):
    pass

class TestAsyncApp(App):
    def build(self):
        img = 'edited_background.jpg' 
        return CenteredAsyncImage(source=img)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestAsyncApp().run()
```

**Clock Widget**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
import time


class Time(Label):
    def updateTime(self,*args):
        self.text = time.asctime()
class TimeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        t=Time()
        Clock.schedule_interval(t.updateTime,1)
        return(t)

TimeApp().run()
```

I need to display both in a single window and clock should be in the top right most corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder

from centeredasyncimage import CenteredAsyncImage
from timelabel import Time

theroot = Builder.load_string('''
RelativeLayout:
    CenteredAsyncImage:
        source: 'img.jpg'
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'top': 1.0}
    Time:
        id: time
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
        pos_hint: {'right': 1.0, 'top': 1.0}
''')


class TheApp(App):
    def build(self):

        # schedule the start of the clock
        Clock.schedule_once(self.start_time_updates)
        return theroot

    def start_time_updates(self, dt):
        t = self.root.ids.time
        # schedule the clock update every second
        Clock.schedule_interval(t.updateTime,1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TheApp().run()
```

This assumes that the `CenteredAsyncImge` is defined in a file named `centeredasyncimage.py` and `Time` is defined in a file named `timelabel.py`.

In those files, the code that is used to run an `App` needs to be protected from running when the file is imported. That is done using `if __name__ == '__main__':`. So, I have modified those files slightly:

timelabel.py:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import time


class Time(Label):
    def updateTime(self,*args):
        self.text = time.asctime()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.clock import Clock
    class TimeApp(App):
        def build(self):
            t=Time()
            Clock.schedule_interval(t.updateTime,1)
            return(t)

    TimeApp().run()
```

and centeredasyncimage.py:

```
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<CenteredAsyncImage>:
    allow_stretch: True
    keep_ratio: True
    size_hint_y: None
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    height: dp(800)
    mipmap: True
''')


class CenteredAsyncImage(AsyncImage):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.app import App
    class TestAsyncApp(App):
        def build(self):
            img = 'edited_background.jpg'
            return CenteredAsyncImage(source=img)

    TestAsyncApp().run()
```

If you want to update the image source for the `CenteredAsyncImage`, you can just modify the file containing  the `App` as:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from centeredasyncimage import CenteredAsyncImage
from timelabel import Time

theroot = Builder.load_string('''
RelativeLayout:
    CenteredAsyncImage:
        id: casi
        source: 'img.jpg'   # default image (this is optional)
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'top': 1.0}
    Time:
        id: time
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
        pos_hint: {'right': 1.0, 'top': 1.0}
''')


class TheApp(App):
    img_source = StringProperty()  # property to hold image source
    def build(self):
        self.bind(img_source=self.set_casi_source)   # bind source property
        Clock.schedule_once(self.start_time_updates)
        return theroot

    def set_casi_source(self, app, val, *args):
        # this sets the image source
        self.root.ids.casi.source = val

    def start_time_updates(self, dt):
        t = self.root.ids.time
        Clock.schedule_interval(t.updateTime,1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TheApp().run()
```

The `img_source` `StringProperty` will contain the source for the `CenteredAsyncImage`. The call to `self.bind` arranges for any change to the `img_source` to trigger a call to `set_casi_source()`, which sets the `source` for the `CenteredAsyncImage`. Note that setting the `img_source` inside the `build()` method will fail, since it uses `ids` and they are not setup yet in the `build()` method. So, any time after the `App` is built, just changing the `img_source` property will change the `CenteredAsyncImage`.

Comment: Hi @John, Thanks for your replay. This code is working. But i cannot hard code the image name in code.  I want to update the image with my main python file. So whats the modification that i have to do for that?